# Django Forms Validation Check is not working

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am giving this validation rule in my django forms, so when the field is none then it will rasie validation error but validationcoming ervey time , i meant when is none or not none i am getting the validationerror every time, How i solve this issue.
models.py

```html
class Check(models.Model):
  use_for_car = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Forms.py

```html
class CheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    translated_names = TranslationField()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CheckForm, self).clean()
        use_for_car = self.cleaned_data.get("use_for_car")
        
        if use_for_car is None:  
            raise ValidationError("Use For Car NEED TO BE FILLED ")
        return use_for_registrations

    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = models.Check
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already the case, since you did not specify [**`blank=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank), this means that the form field is required, so this means that for the form field, [**`required=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required), and for a [**`BooleanField`** form field <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield), this means:

> Since all Field subclasses have `required=True` by default, the validation condition here is important. If you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either `True` or `False` (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in `required=False` when creating the `BooleanField`.

You thus can simply let Django do the work:

```
class CheckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    translated_names = TranslationField()

    # no clean override

    class Meta:
        model = models.Check
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Hi @williem when i should pass required = False?

Comment: @Yen: you use `blank=True` in the model field to allow both `True` and `False`.